# Accessing an audio file as a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, matrix, signal-processing, audio-processing

I am new to MATLAB.
I have written the following code in it.

```
load handel.mat ;
filename = 'handel.wav';
audiowrite(filename,y,Fs);
disp('playing for a second') ;
samples = [20*Fs,21*Fs];
[y,Fs] = audioread('handle.mp3',samples);
sound(y,Fs);
disp('saving this output sound') ;
filename = 'handel.wav';
audiowrite(filename,y,Fs);
info = audioinfo('handel.wav') 
disp('ploting the graph') ;
[f,Fs] = audioread('handel.wav') ;
N = length(f);
slength = N/Fs;
t = linspace(0, N/Fs, N)
plot(t, f)
clear y Fs
```

This codes reads an mp3 audio file, saves it as a .wav and plots it as a graph. It also shows some column values in the command window when i run it.
What i want to do is to manipulate the audio file as a matrix. But i have no idea how to get the audio in the form of a matrix. Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do [audioread()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html) it returns

- y:  audio data as a matrix
- Fs: sampling frequency

So, your good to go!

Comment: thanks for the help!